# Negate Image Without gray Overlapping

Tags: c++, image-processing, colors, 3d, textures

Image negative effect is typically done like this:

```
pixel = rgb(1, 1 ,1) - pixel
```

but if the pixel color is close to gray, than:

```
pixel = rgb(1, 1, 1) - rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) = 0.5
```

That's not a problem and it's how it should be, but for me it is, I am making a crosshair texture in my 3D game, which will be drawn in the center of the screen and I want it to have negative effect, reason for it is clearity, if I were to make crosshair white, it would not be visible when looking on white objects (I know I can make it with black outline so it is visible, but thats ugly), but it still has problems for grayish colors as I described, what can be done to fix that?

Comment: In my product, if the color is close to grey, we uses black.  If the color is close to black, the code uses white.

Comment: Yea, thats simple, but I would like an elegant solution and can't think much

Comment: If you don't like white crosshair with black outline, how about white-black-white dashed line, so the line is still 1-pixel wide? If that's still not good, then keep your original idea, use @Eljay's idea ONLY when your input color is close to gray.

Comment: I don't like that either, but either way am interested to see solution to this